# error message can't find symbol?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a double string. I thought that this is one way to assign values. I know there are better ways, but it was suggested by my teacher to do it this way. However when I put this in I get errors for each one stating:

can't find symbol cellPhoneNumbers 
']' expected

Ultimately what I am trying to do is create a graph that looks something like this

Chile   ***********
Sweden  *****
Peru    *******************

```
public class GraphNumbers
{
    String[][] cellPhoneNumbers = new String[5][1];
    cellPhoneNumbers[0][0] = "Chile";
    cellPhoneNumbers[0][1] = "21";
    cellPhoneNumbers[1][0] = "Sweden";
    cellPhoneNumbers[1][1] = "11";
    cellPhoneNumbers[2][0] = "Peru";
    cellPhoneNumbers[2][1] = "33";
    cellPhoneNumbers[3][0] = "Bulgaria";
    cellPhoneNumbers[3][1] = "10";
    cellPhoneNumbers[4][0] = "Guatemala";
    cellPhoneNumbers[4][1] = "18";

}
```

Why am I receiving this message?

Comment: you can't have [0][1] position in a [5][1] array. You only have [0][0], [1][0],[2][0] like upto [4][0].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the code must be placed in a method for example:

```
public class GraphNumbers
{
    //changed the size of the array so you could do what you want
    //you must have had a misscount when you originally made it
    String[][] cellPhoneNumbers = new String[5][2];

    //put in constructor or another appropriately named method
    public GraphNumbers()
    {
        cellPhoneNumbers[0][0] = "Chile";
        cellPhoneNumbers[0][1] = "21";
        cellPhoneNumbers[1][0] = "Sweden";
        cellPhoneNumbers[1][1] = "11";
        cellPhoneNumbers[2][0] = "Peru";
        cellPhoneNumbers[2][1] = "33";
        cellPhoneNumbers[3][0] = "Bulgaria";
        cellPhoneNumbers[3][1] = "10";
        cellPhoneNumbers[4][0] = "Guatemala";
        cellPhoneNumbers[4][1] = "18";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per Java language syntax, you cannot put executable statements in class. Those should be put in either method/constructor/code blocks.

So you need to move these statements:

```
cellPhoneNumbers[0][0] = "Chile";
cellPhoneNumbers[0][1] = "21";
cellPhoneNumbers[1][0] = "Sweden";
cellPhoneNumbers[1][1] = "11";
cellPhoneNumbers[2][0] = "Peru";
cellPhoneNumbers[2][1] = "33";
cellPhoneNumbers[3][0] = "Bulgaria";
cellPhoneNumbers[3][1] = "10";
cellPhoneNumbers[4][0] = "Guatemala";
cellPhoneNumbers[4][1] = "18";
```

to appropriate place, maybe in a constructor.

Also your code is overflowing the array in stamens such as :

```
cellPhoneNumbers[0][1] = "21";
```

so you need the second dimension of array to be of size 2 and not 1. Change this

```
String[][] cellPhoneNumbers = new String[5][1];
```

to

```
String[][] cellPhoneNumbers = new String[5][2];
```

Comment: and even after that u can't have position like [0][1] in a [5][1] array

Comment: took care of that in my ex